# How can I add my logo to my rss feed?

Tags: xml, rss, feed, atom-feed

how can I add my logo to my rss feed?

Answer (score 2):

Atom RSS

```
<feed>
   ...
   <icon>http://example.org/favicon.ico</icon>
   <logo>http://example.org/logo.jpg</logo>
   ...
</feed>
```

RSS

```
<channel>
   ...
   <image>
    <url>http://www.snook.ca/img/rss_banner.gif</url>
    <title>Snook.ca</title>
    <link>http://www.snook.ca/jonathan/</link>
    <width>111</width>
    <height>32</height>
    <description>Snook.ca features tips, tricks, and bookmarks on web development</description>
  </image>
  ...
</channel>
```

[Reference](http://snook.ca/archives/rss/add_logo_to_feed)

Answer (score 0):

This will work for Atom feed:

```
<feed>
   <logo><path to image></logo>
   <icon><path to icon></icon>
</feed>
```

This will work RSS feeds:

```
<channel>
   ...
   <image>
    <url>url to image </url>
    <title>image title </title>
    <link><path to image></link>
    <width>pixel width</width>
    <height>pixel height</height>
    <description>description here </description>
  </image>
  ...
</channel>
```